# How do I subset column variables in DF1 based on the important variables I got in DF2?

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr, reshape2

I have 2 df's like this

```
ID = c('x1','x2','x5')
df1 <- data.frame(ID)

x1 = c(1,2,3,4,5)
x2 = c(11,12,13,14,15)
x3 = c(21,22,23,24,25)
x4 = c(31,32,33,34,35)
x5 = c(41,42,43,44,45)
df2 <- data.frame(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5)
```

Desired output

```
  x1 x2 x5
1  1 11 41
2  2 12 42
3  3 13 43
4  4 14 44
5  5 15 45
```

I would like my new dataset to contain only those variables that are identified in df1 as important (i.e: x1,x2,x5) with the values from df2.

In this simple dataset, I know I could do this but just removing x3,x4 in df2 but ideally I would like to apply it to a larger data set where I have more than 100 variables and hence would like to do it programatically.

Comment: `df2[as.character(df1$ID)]`

Comment: Awesome I applied it to a bigger dataset and it worked like charm!!. Thanks David. So "unlist" did the trick. I will use it from now.

Comment: No, `as.character` did. If `df1$ID` is already of character class then, just `df2[df1$ID]` will work. Try it on `df1 <- data.frame(ID, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

Comment: In my large dataset, df1 is a factor and hence unlist was simple to use.

Comment: `unlist` will keep it a factor and thus the sub-setting will be wrong. Use `df2[as.character(df1$ID)]` like I showed.

Comment: Yup you were right. I just used the "df2[as.character(df1$ID)]" and was fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't find a dupe so here goes- simply subset by the values of `as.character(df1$ID)` as in

```
df2[as.character(df1$ID)] ## Or just `df2[df1$ID]` if its already a character
#   x1 x2 x5
# 1  1 11 41
# 2  2 12 42
# 3  3 13 43
# 4  4 14 44
# 5  5 15 45
```

The reason for `as.character` is in order to avoid sub-setting by `df1$ID` underlying storage mode (integer) rather by it's levels

---

Though this question is tagged with `data.table`, so we could also do this by reference (if we have a `data.table`)- no need to convert to `character`

```
setDT(df2)[, setdiff(names(df2), df1$ID) := NULL]
df2
#    x1 x2 x5
# 1:  1 11 41
# 2:  2 12 42
# 3:  3 13 43
# 4:  4 14 44
# 5:  5 15 45
```